# How to remove square parentheses and text within from strings in R

Tags: r, regex, string, gsub

I have encounter a problem in R language to process a data frame (`test_dataframe`) column (`test_column`) value like below:
Original strings in the column:

```
test_column
6.77[9]
5.92[10]
2.98[103]
```

I need to **remove square brackets and any character inside square brackets**, so the target value is below:

```
test_column
6.77
5.92
2.98
```

I tried with `gsub` function in R language, but not very lucky to resolve it, could someone help to figure out ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would use:

```
input <- c("6.77[9]", "5.92[10]", "2.98[103]")
gsub("\\[.*?\\]", "", input)

[1] "6.77" "5.92" "2.98"
```

The regex pattern `\[.*?\]` should match any quoted terms in square brackets, and using `gsub` would tell R to replace all such terms.

Comment: Wow, thanks for quick help, this pattern works perfect, the `.*?` which present any character inside square brackets is the part i am not able to find out before, again, thanks !

Answer (score 3):

You can use `sub` and remove everything after square brackets.

```
df$test_column <- sub("\\[.*", "", df$test_column)
df
#  test_column
#1        6.77
#2        5.92
#3        2.98
```

You might want to wrap the output from the `sub` in `as.numeric`.

---

If there is always a numeric value ahead as shown in the example you can also use `parse_number`

```
readr::parse_number(df$test_column)
#[1] 6.77 5.92 2.98
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(test_column = c("6.77[9]", "5.92[10]", "2.98[103]"
)), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Yeah, thanks Shah, i have tried your solution also, your idea is also perfect, especially the detail for convert to numeric, thanks for quick help !

Answer (score 2):

We can use `str_remove` from `stringr`

```
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)
df %>%
   mutate(test_column = str_remove(test_column, "\\[.*"))
#  test_column
#1        6.77
#2        5.92
#3        2.98
```

Answer (score 0):

This might be also another option using `str_remove_all()` from `stringr` package `version: 1.5.1` that creates capturing group using `parentheses` and then convert to numeric vector by piping to `as.double()`:

```
str_remove_all(c("6.77[9]", "5.92[10]", "2.98[103]")
               ,pattern = "(\\[.*\\])") %>%
                as.double()

[1] 6.77 5.92 2.98
```